# VR Carboard api without screen split screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

Can you use the VR Carboard api without screen split screen ?

My point is to use the gyroscope rotation result of the VR feature, without the VR feature.

I found these : Disable VR at start https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-remove-vr-split-screen-when-app-starts-unity-5-6.470962/ And many more but not helpfull help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I made it works !

Enable VR inside the player prefs, set the first VR option to None, second to cardboard. Then

```
 void Start()
     {
         UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.LoadDeviceByName(UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.supportedDevices[1]);
         UnityEngine.XR.XRSettings.enabled = false;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         Camera.main.transform.localRotation = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.CenterEye);
     }
```

Thanks https://forum.unity.com/threads/disable-stereo-rendering-with-cardboard-and-gear-sdk.497214/